# 2 Direction Motor

Tags: c++, motor, arduino-nano

Using an  Arduino-Nano, I'm trying to make a circuit that will change the direction of a motor based on two inputs. The input from the Arduino will be amplified by a transistor. Here's the code:

```
int rightIn = 2;
int rightOut = 3;
int leftIn = 4;
int leftOut = 5;
int rightVal = 0;
int leftVal = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(rightIn, INPUT);
  pinMode(leftIn, INPUT);
  pinMode(rightOut, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(leftOut, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  rightVal = digitalRead(rightIn);
  Serial.println(rightVal);
  leftVal = digitalRead(leftIn);
  if ((rightVal == HIGH) || (leftVal == HIGH)) {
    if (rightVal == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(rightOut, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(leftOut, LOW);
    }
    if (leftVal == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(rightOut, LOW);
      digitalWrite(leftOut, HIGH);
    }
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(rightOut, LOW);
    digitalWrite(leftOut, LOW);  
  }
}
```

And the arduino wiring:

- Pins 3 and 5 are attached to the motors power and ground
- Pins 2 ad 4 go to an seprate inputs

Comment: And your question is?   The Stack Exchange sites require stating a clear, answerable problem

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - you have stated what you want. Now you need to describe what is happening, compared to what you want to have happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing up your `rightVal` and `rightIn`, and your `leftVal` and `leftIn`.

```
rightVal = digitalRead(rightIn);
....
if (rightIn == HIGH) {
```

Comment: I'm just testing it with an led. In theory, would the code work?

Comment: Thanks, now that that's fixed could it work?

Comment: Probably, yes - as long as your circuit is up to it

Comment: Your HIGH/LOW signals will have to switch a motor's pole between power and ground - so you need more than "a transistor". You will need at least two each side in a H-bridge arrangement.

Comment: my motor only needs 3.3  volts, is 2 transistors per side really necessary?

Comment: Well, yes. How else are you going to switch 4 possible connections?